# How to manage multiple user indexes in spring data elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

In spring data elasticsearch one model class/entity represents or maps to an index and type.

eg :-

```
@Document(indexName = "myindex",type="mytype")
public class DocumentModel {
    ......
}
```

I have a use case in which I should index data in different es indexes with *same structure*. If that's the case how can I represent all of those indices with this model class ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Data ES supports using SpEL expressions in the index name of the `@Document` annotation, like this:

```
@Document(indexName = "myindex-#{userId}", type="mytype")
public class DocumentModel {
    ......
}
```

Hence, you have access to the [whole context offered by SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) in order to create your index names.

**UPDATE**

If you're using `elasticsearchTemplate`, there is a simpler variant, you can do it like this:

```
IndexQuery indexQuery = new IndexQueryBuilder()
     .withId(docModel.getId())
     .withObject(docModel)
     .withIndex("myindex"+docModel.getUserId()).build();
```

the call to `withIndex("...")` will override whatever index name you have in the `@Document` annotation

Comment: In that case how can I create an entity object with myindex32(provided user id is 32). Can you provide an example ?

Comment: In my example above, the index will be named after the entity's `userId` field value.

Comment: So userId will be a field within class DocumentModel. Right ?

Comment: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'userId' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext' - maybe not public?    Any idea about this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120395/discussion-between-sachin-and-val).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361746/how-to-search-inside-all-types-in-elastic-index-using-spring-data-elasticsearch  Similar question.Can you help me with this ?

Comment: `withIndex` is not longer available